# JavaScript inline code not showing up in browser

Tags: javascript

I am taking my first JavaScript class. The first two exercises I did worked great. This one however is not. Nothing all all shows up in the browser. It is just a white page. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "_//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var degFahren = Number(prompt("Enter the degrees Fahrenheit",32));
      var degCent; 
      degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren - 32));
      document.write(degFahren + "\xB0 Fahrenheit is " + degCent + "\xB0 centigrade<br />";
      if (degCet < 0) { document.write("That's below the freezing point of water");}
      if (degCent == 100) { document.write("That's the boiling point of water"); }
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo; `degCet` > `degCent` in your first `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks...that is what was not letting my if statements work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code should work. These are **easy to spot** problems, just open up your **javascript console** *(F12)* and you'll see you have an extra `)` on line 8, and a missing one line 10. There was also a typo on `degCent`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "_//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var degFahren = Number(prompt("Enter the degrees Fahrenheit",32));
    var degCent; 
    degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren - 32);
    document.write(degFahren + "\xB0 Fahrenheit is " + degCent + "\xB0 centigrade<br />");
    if (degCent < 0) { document.write("That's below the freezing point of water");}
    if (degCent == 100) { document.write("That's the boiling point of water"); }
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I did not see that.

Comment: @floyd Don't be sorry if you did not know about the javascript console, but always use it in the future, it will save you a lot of time ;)